# Mohnhaft 1928 meaning

Tags: meaning, translation

I have been sent a document from Lübeck dated 1928 where the word "mohnhaft" in reference to a record made about my grandmother. Can you help? I'll gladly send a copy of the document.

Comment: You should supply a copy of the document.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, except for a misreading, this can be answered by a dictionary. An answer would not be useful to anyone else in the future. I have therefore now voted to close, I should have done that in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

This word makes no sense.

- [Mohn](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohn) (noun) = [papaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papaver)
- -haft (suffix) = -ish, -ly, -ous, ...

So, *mohnhaft* would mean *papaverish, papaverly, papaverous* or something like that. But that makes absolutely no sense, especially in an official document.

But there is a German word that exists and makes perfect sense, and its natural habitat is even the realm of official documents:

#### wohnhaft = resident

**an einem Ort wohnhaft sein = to be resident in a place**

The first part (*wohn-*) is the stem of the verb *wohnen.*

- wohnen [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wohnen) [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/wohnen)
  to live (at a home), to reside, to room, ...

The second part (*-haft*) is the same as just described, but when added to a verb, it is often better to translate is as *-ing,* although that is not exactly the same, but it's the best you can get in English, because by adding *-haft* to a word, the resulting word is an adjective. But adding *-ing* in English does not change the status of a verb being a verb.

Another way, that only works with a small number of verbs, is adding *-ent* to turn it into an adjective. This works well with *to reside → resident* but not with the other verbs that can be used as translation of *wohnen.*

So, here are translations that work:

> Er ist in Wien wohnhaft. = He is living in Vienna.
> Er ist in Wien wohnhaft. = He is resident in Vienna.

However, as *living* is not an adjective, but *resident* is, the word *resident* comes closer to the original meaning of the German word.

Comment: The question is obviously based on a reading error and has no value for anyone but OP. Everything else stated in this answer can be found in a dictionary.